# Fit Image in Thumbnails Wordpress - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, image

I tried many tricks, googled many websites, used many wordpress plugins but failed & fedup. I am running a coupons/ deals website, my problem is i want to display the product image completely without any crop even if it is small in size.

The original image is https://postimg.org/image/ue5aamx8t/
but cropped image showing in my website is http://couponfun.in/product/kanvas-katha-tote-%E2%82%B983/

please help.

Comment: hello @Sathish,Where is your images in site?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this thing,

The category images are the same size as shop_image (or Catalog) thumbnail. WooCommerce handles its product thumbnails in its settings:
WooCommerce->Settings>Products>Display

You can change its height, width, and toggle the hard crop on/off.

**Note : After changing the image sizes you will need to regenerate thumbnails. (Link in same page you can see.)**

[image: HardCrop setting]

Comment: what actually you are do?

Comment: when you upload image it croped into some image

Comment: did you regenrate thumb??

Comment: I would get higher resolution images.

Try adding this at the end of styles.css to stop enlargement:
`.woocommerce div.product div.images img {   width: auto !important;}`

Comment: i want a thumbnail which has a complete image without any cut. Like this https://m.freekaamaal.com/deals/dettol-original-bodywash-250-ml-at-rs-102

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: indexer please check my website couponfun.in

Comment: please give me any original image name

Comment: sorry I didn't understand

Comment: You please contact with your theme support.

Comment: i contacted the theme supporters but he is not giving any answer https://themeforest.net/item/multipurpose-listing-wordpress-theme-coupons-discounts-marketplace-indexer/17869108/comments               my user id is tcac

Comment: I have to research regarding this theme then I can say about this

Comment: @SathishKumar you have to check inside <Your theme >is there any other theme folder?

Comment: No. There is no other theme folder. If you wants i Wii give the wordpress user name & password

Comment: Yes,please send me at vasimmca007atgmail